# Minimum Tube length distance between objective lens to tube lens

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, microscopy

The maximum tube length between objective lens → tube lens ([reference here](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/microscopy/using-tube-lenses-with-infinity-corrected-objectives/))

MaxTubeLength = (TubeLensPupilDia-ObjectiveExitPupilDia)  x (TubeLens_FL/SensorDiagonal)

You can use the [calculator](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/tech-tools/infinite-conjugate-tube-length/) here. This formula gives the maximum value for L. Breaking this rule will result in vignetting.

My questions:

1. What is the **minimum value for L** that can be used without distorting the image?
2. Are there any constraints on the **minimum value for L** that should be used without affecting magnification or image quality?
3. In other words, can it be **zero**?

[image: 1]

Comment: Distortion is a separate variable from vignetting (or from focus itself).   As to minimum length,  you need to do a raytrace based on the output angles from the objective in question, the external working distance, and the targeted virtual object distance for the ocular lens, which will drive the eye relief vs. vignetting limit.